# Formatting a PDF document

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, highlighting, markup

I just have Adobe PDF Reader, not an Adobe professional version. Is there any freeware or any other way through which I can highlight the text that is to be noted/marked?

I want to use Adobe Reader as my PDF reader... don't want to try Nitropdf or pdf suite etc..

Answer (score 2):

**[PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/PDF/PDF-XChange-Viewer.shtml)** has this option:

Tools > Comment and Markup Tools > Highlight Text Tool

[image]

*PDF-XChange Viewer is freeware, a [portable version](http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/Portable-PDF-XChange-Viewer-Screenshot-93052.html) is also available.

If you get the installer, during the installation you will be asked if you want to use PDF-Xchange Viewer as your default PDF viewer. Do not choose this option if you wish to keep Adobe Reader as default program - or get the portable version, which does not have to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of many open-source (and therefore free) options ([here](http://www.cogniview.com/convert-pdf-to-excel/post/pdf-editing-creation-50-open-sourcefree-alternatives-to-adobe-acrobat/) might be a good place to start looking). [This page](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/acrrfaq.html) says that:

> You cannot make permanent changes to PDF files using Adobe Reader; however you can perform many edit-like functions using Adobe Reader if the author has enabled these functions using Acrobat 7.0 Professional. For example, you can highlight text and add comments on sticky notes.

So it would seem that you may be able to what you are asking about, though exactly what constitutes a "permanent change" is not mentioned.

I personally would try [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), as I have had a very nice time with it in the past and it is likely have the ability to import and export documents.

Comment: Note that OpenOffice alone cannot import PDF file. You need the PDF Import Extension ( http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Pdf_Import_Extension ). Even the import extension does not support all PDf files.